# *date = "Sunday"; vs int *number = 7;

Tags: c

I have such a snippet of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char *date = "Sunday";
    //int *number = 7;

    printf("Today is %s, the 7 days of this week", date);
}
```

It worked as intended and print

```
$ ./a.out
Today is Sunday, the 7 days of this week
```

Nonetheless, when I de-comment

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char *date = "Sunday";
    int *number = 7;

    printf("Today is %s, the %d days of this week", date, *number);
}
```

It report error:

```
$ cc draft.c
draft.c:5:10: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'int *' with an expression of type
      'int' [-Wint-conversion]
    int *number = 7;
         ^        ~
1 warning generated.
```

What's the problem with my code?

Comment: You say `de-comment` but your code snippet includes `number` still being commented.

Comment: What resource are you using for learning C?

Comment: the resource: http://www.it.uc3m.es/pbasanta/asng/course_notes/index_en.html, could you please introduce one? @StoryTeller

Comment: You are setting the address held to `7`, e.g. `int *number = 7;` That is way down in the system-reserved portion on memory on virtually every system and guaranteed to SegFault on access. Just use `int number = 7;` and then `"number"` in `printf` (without the quotes) Remember, a pointer is simply a normal variable that holds the *address of* something else as its value.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: "*...  and guaranteed to SegFault on access*" as done here: "`, *number);`".

Comment: `int *number = 7;` initializes the pointer `number`, not the int `*number`. Same as `char *date = "Sunday";` initializes the pointer `date`, not the char `*date`.

Comment: That resource doesn't seem like a particularly good one for a novice C programmer. I suggest you give [Programming in C](https://www.amazon.com/Programming-C-4th-Developers-Library/dp/0321776410) a chance. As the [ACCU review for the third edition](https://accu.org/index.php?module=bookreviews&func=search&rid=110) mentions it's not perfect. But still a good and gentle introduction for a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
int number = 7;
printf("Today is %s, the %d days of this week", date, number);
```

instead of

```
int *number = 7;
printf("Today is %s, the %d days of this week", date, *number);
```

In the first snippet an integer variable is initialize with 7 and its value is printed. In the second snippet a pointer is initialized with address 7 and then the integer value at memory address 7 is printed.

Comment: It's possible to assign an integer to a pointer type without a cast. See [C11 6.3.2.3p5](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p5). **It's not a good idea though** and many compilers will emit a warning.